# Multi-Task Gaussian Process Regression that uses the whole input space to predict

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, nonparametric, gaussian-process

I have been seeing the notebooks provided by GPy to do a Coregionalized Regression.
The notebook is [here](https://bigaidream.gitbooks.io/subsets_ml_cookbook/content/bayes/gp/coregionalized_regression_gpy.html#only-mean-icm). From what I see you have two inputs and two outputs, $X_1$ which is related to $Y_1$ and $X_2$ which is used to model $Y_2$.

Is there any way to make a coregionalized model that uses both the input of X1 and X2 to predict both Y1 and Y2 simultaneously? So, I can in a way have $Y_{i} = f(X_{1}, X_{2})$

I've tried playing with kernels, but it doesn't work well. It seems that, in a way, they are assuming independence of the input space since you have to add to which task the input relates. According to what I understand in the notebook, I would have $Y_{1} = f(X_{1})$ and $Y_{2} = f(X_{2})$ but having $cov(Y_1, Y_{2}) \neq 0$ since there's a task covariance.

e.g:

```
newX = np.arange(100,110)[:,None]
newX = np.hstack([newX,np.ones_like(newX)])
print newX
```